# NSToolbarItem Image Looks Bad Small in Running App but not in Interface Builder

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, nstoolbaritem

I have some NSToolbarItems that I am creating from higher resolution images than the ultimate size they need to be displayed. I am using PDFs for the GIF & PNG images, and a PNG for the MacPaint icon in the Xcode Asset Catalog. The auto-shrunk size looks good in Interface Builder, but bad in the real app. I'm not sure why. Is there anything I can do to alleviate this?

What it looks like in Interface Builder:
[image: IB Version]

What it looks like in the running app:
[image: Running App]

Here's the full size versions in IB:
[image]

You can see in particular the Export MacPaint icon is losing detail. Any tips to change how these are shrunk? Thanks in advance!

Comment: They have to be produced with sizes of 32 x 32 at 72 dpi and of 64 x 64 at 144. dpi

Comment: I think you are saying "don't rely on the auto-scaling". Provide the exact right size bitmaps and all should be well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple answer, as El Tomato mentioned in the comments, is not to rely on the auto-scaling. Just produce bitmaps that are 32 x 32 and 64 x 64.

Comment: Pack them in a TIFF container file if you like.

Comment: I think it would be best to trace this out and make a vector version. The geometry is really simple, so this would be ideal for using a PDF or SVG asset